# Oracle Package Body Compile Errors: SQL Statement Ignored, table or view does not exist

Tags: plsql, oracle12c

I need to wrap a SQL script I wrote into a package because... work.

I get really lost in PL/SQL, and have no idea what I'm doing wrong:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE F_LOG_ARCHIVE_PKG AS 
      PROCEDURE LOG_ARCHIVE;
    END F_LOG_ARCHIVE_PKG;

    /************************ F_BUSINESS_IDENTIFIER ********************************/
    /
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY F_LOG_ARCHIVE_PKG AS
    PROCEDURE LOG_ARCHIVE IS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO LOGARC.F_BUSINESS_IDENTIFIER ("ID", 
          "SERVICE_ID",
          "OPERATION_ID",
          "BUSINESS_IDENTIFIER_NAME",
          "BUSINESS_IDENTIFIER_VALUE",
          "EXCEPTION_ROW_ID",
          "ARCHIVE_DATE")
        SELECT DISTINCT ORIGINAL."ID", 
          ORIGINAL.SERVICE_ID,
          ORIGINAL.OPERATION_ID,
          ORIGINAL.BUSINESS_IDENTIFIER_NAME,
          ORIGINAL.BUSINESS_IDENTIFIER_VALUE,
          ORIGINAL.EXCEPTION_ROW_ID,
          sysdate
        FROM LOGUSR.F_BUSINESS_IDENTIFIER ORIGINAL
        --Latest exception date based on service id and operation id
        INNER JOIN (SELECT F_EXCEPTION.SERVICE_ID,
                  F_SERVICE_OPERATION_NAME.ID AS OPERATION_ID,
                  MAX(RECORD_CREATED_DATE) AS RECORD_CREATED_DATE, 
                  MAX(EXCEPTION_DATE) AS EXCEPTION_DATE
                  FROM LOGUSR.F_EXCEPTION
                  INNER JOIN LOGUSR.F_SERVICE_OPERATION_NAME
                  ON F_EXCEPTION.OPERATION_NAME = F_SERVICE_OPERATION_NAME.OPERATION_NAME
                  GROUP BY F_EXCEPTION.SERVICE_ID,F_SERVICE_OPERATION_NAME.ID) EXCEPTION_DATE
          ON ORIGINAL.SERVICE_ID = EXCEPTION_DATE.SERVICE_ID
          AND ORIGINAL.OPERATION_ID = EXCEPTION_DATE.OPERATION_ID
        --Service name to join to F_SERVICE_LOGSTATUS table
        INNER JOIN LOGUSR.F_SERVICE_NAME
          ON ORIGINAL.SERVICE_ID = F_SERVICE_NAME.ID
        --Operation name to join to F_SERVICE_LOGSTATUS table
        INNER JOIN LOGUSR.F_SERVICE_OPERATION_NAME
          ON ORIGINAL.OPERATION_ID = F_SERVICE_OPERATION_NAME.ID
        --Archive strategy
        INNER JOIN LOGUSR.F_SERVICE_LOGSTATUS
          ON F_SERVICE_NAME.SERVICE_NAME = F_SERVICE_LOGSTATUS.SERVICE_NAME
          AND F_SERVICE_OPERATION_NAME.OPERATION_NAME = F_SERVICE_LOGSTATUS.OPERATION_NAME
        WHERE F_SERVICE_LOGSTATUS.ARCHIVE_FLAG = 'Y'
        AND F_SERVICE_LOGSTATUS.ARCHIVE_DAYS <= (sysdate-EXCEPTION_DATE.EXCEPTION_DATE);
```

SNIP

```
    END LOG_ARCHIVE; 
    END F_LOG_ARCHIVE_PKG;
```

Errors returned:

Error(4,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(4,24): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

The DBA recently updated to role to give the user write access to both schemas.

Comment: Is the package owner different from LOGUSR? If so, does the package owner have privileges to the table(s) in LOGUSR, granted **directly** (not through roles)? If not, that's probably the problem.

Comment: Thanks mathguy, looks like that was the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your package references tables in two schemas, LOGUSR and LOGARC. When we build a package we can only reference objects in our schema (the package owner) and objects in other schemas where privileges have been granted to us **directly**. Privileges granted through a role are no good for this, (because of the Oracle security model).

You say,

> "The DBA recently updated to role to give the user write access to both schemas."

So, depending on which schema owns your package you need to ask your DBA to  grant you privileges on the other schema's objects.